# How to assess Cell from another worksheet in Excel VBA code

Tags: excel, vba

am trying to check if a specific cell (G12) from a Worksheet ("Enter_information") is blank (*am using an excel worksheet instead of a user form since i need to include a complex table for user to input data*). my current worksheet is ("DQA_Database") and when i instruct code to assess the cell (G12), i keep getting an 1004 error. the code is as below:

```
Private Sub cmdAdd_Click()

'Adding info to database
Dim iRow As Long
Dim ws As Worksheet
Set ws = Worksheets("DQA_Database")

'find first empty row in database
iRow = ws.Cells.Find(What:="*", SearchOrder:=xlRows, _
    SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, LookIn:=xlValues).Row + 1

'check for missing facility info (if cell is blank)
If Trim(Me.Range(G12).Value) = "" Then
  Me.Range(G12).SetFocus
  MsgBox "Please select a district"
  Exit Sub
End If
```

please, help a brother.

Comment: `Range("G12")`?

Comment: A `Range` doesn't have a `SetFocus` method btw.

Comment: Thanks @BigBen, i notice indeed the SetFocus method is giving me a Run-time error 438. Any suggestion of a syntax i can use to have the assessed Cell highlighted once the code identifies that it has been left blank?

Comment: If that range is on a different sheet, then `.Activate` the sheet and `.Select` the cell.

Answer (score 0):

Without rewriting your code, here's an example of pointing to a cell on another sheet, reading its value, and setting focus to it (well, selecting it actually)

```vb
Private Sub testButton_Click()

    Dim s As Worksheet
    Dim r As Range
    Set s = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Enter_information")
    Set r = s.Range("G12")
    Debug.Print r.Value
    s.Select
    r.Select

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks Julien, much appreciated

Comment: Related to this, am getting a run-time error 91 when trying to write the input: 

```
Private Sub cmdAdd_Click()

Dim iRow As Long
Dim ws As Worksheet
Set ws = Worksheets("DQA_Database")

'find first empty row in database
iRow = ws.Cells.Find(What:="*", SearchOrder:=xlRows, _
    SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, LookIn:=xlValues).Row + 1

'Write input to "DQA_Database"

With ws
  .Cells(iRow, 1).Value = Me.Range("G12").Value
  .Cells(iRow, 2).Value = Me.Range("P12").Value
  .Cells(iRow, 3).Value = Me.Range("P14").Value
End With
End Sub
```
Bear with me, am still a novice!

Comment: @TMJ sorry but debuging VBA is not the easiest thing, let alone with flat code in a comment, not knowing which line failed... you should ask another question for that. Leave a link here, I'll take a look when I'm at my actual keyboard :). Oh and consider upvoting the answer if it helped